# How to open a window object in the indicated position, with indicative dimensions, which will show the content of the page indicated in the form?

Tags: javascript, window

At the moment I have to make a program that will open a window object in javascript, which will have the dimensions and coordinates x and z added from the keyboard and not in the javascript code. Unfortunately I wasn't allowed to do this, and I didn't find anything on the internet to help me. And if anyone could help and explain me then I will be very grateful.

This is an example how this should look

[image]

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: `window.open(urlValuefromField,"new","height="+heightFromField+",width="+widthFromField+",top="+posXFromField+",left="+posYFromField)`